# Calculate percentages with 2 fields in the GROUP BY clause - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following results that list different departments within different offices. Each departments hours and cost has been calculated for each office.

```
OfficeCode    Department     Total Hours     Total Costs
---------------------------------------------------------
OFC-UK        Buying         44              50850
OFC-UK        Design         42              30008
OFC-UK        R&D            28              70600
OFC-AZ        Buying         52              30801
OFC-AZ        Design         34              50080
OFC-BG        Buying         25              40030
OFC-BG        Design         37              10020
```

The above results come from the following query:

```
SELECT office.office_code,
       department.department_description,       
       CAST(SUM(timesheet_entry.timesheet_entry_hour) + (SUM(timesheet_entry.timesheet_entry_minute)/60) as float) as total_hours,
       SUM((timesheet_entry.timesheet_entry_hour + ((timesheet_entry.timesheet_entry_minute)/60)) * person.person_rate) as 'total_cost'
       FROM timesheet_entry

INNER JOIN user
        ON user.user_obj = timesheet_entry.user_obj          
INNER JOIN person
    ON person.person_obj = user.person_obj
INNER JOIN department
        ON department.department_obj = user.department_id
INNER JOIN office
        ON office.office_id = timesheet_entry.office_id
        
GROUP BY timesheet_entry.office_code, department.department_description
ORDER BY office.office_code, department.department_description;
```

I need to calculate the percentages of the total_hours and total_cost fields, per department, per office. Such as an example of the desired results:

```
OfficeCode    Department     Total Hours     HoursPercentage     Total Costs     CostPercentage
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OFC-UK        Buying         44              38.59               50850           33.57
OFC-UK        Design         42              36.84               30008           19.81        
OFC-UK        R&D            28              24.56               70600           46.61
OFC-AZ        Buying         52              etc                 etc             etc
OFC-AZ        Design         34              etc                 etc             etc
OFC-BG        Buying         25              etc                 etc             etc
OFC-BG        Design         37              etc                 etc             etc
```

I tried to put the results into a temp-table, and then calculate the percentages ontop of that with the GROUP BY, but it seems it doesnt take the groups into consideration. Is there a better, and accurate, way to do this?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl

SELECT office.office_code,
       department.department_description,       
       CAST(SUM(timesheet_entry.timesheet_entry_hour) + (SUM(timesheet_entry.timesheet_entry_minute)/60) as float) as total_hours,
       SUM((timesheet_entry.timesheet_entry_hour + ((timesheet_entry.timesheet_entry_minute)/60)) * person.person_rate) as 'total_cost'
       FROM timesheet_entry

INNER JOIN user
        ON user.user_obj = timesheet_entry.user_obj          
INNER JOIN person
    ON person.person_obj = user.person_obj
INNER JOIN department
        ON department.department_obj = user.department_id
INNER JOIN office
        ON office.office_id = timesheet_entry.office_id
        
GROUP BY timesheet_entry.office_code, department.department_description
ORDER BY office.office_code, department.department_description;


SELECT 
    OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.office_code,
    OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.department_description,  
    OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.total_hours,
    OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.total_hours * 100 /  
        (SELECT SUM(OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.total_hours) FROM OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl) AS 'department_percentage_of_total_hours',
    OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.total_cost,
    OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.total_cost * 100 / (SELECT 
            SUM(OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.total_cost)
        FROM
            OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl) AS 'department_percentage_of_total_cost'
FROM
    OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl
GROUP BY OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.office_code, OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl.department_description;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE OfficeDepartmentTotalsTbl;
```

Comment: Where the value `38.59` is taken from? show the expression which uses source table data and computes it. The same for `33.57`. Also provide precise MySQL version.

Comment: Hi Akina, so if you look at the first 3 records in the example, there are three departments (Buying. Design, R&D) for the UK office (OFC-UK).

Thus the first record of 38.59% was calculated by taking the hours for the department / sum of the hours of all the departments in that office, multipled by 100.

Thus [44/(44 + 42 + 28)] * 100 = 38.59% of the hours was spent in the Buying department for the UK office.

Comment: Well, this is clear. Now answer the latter question: *Also provide precise MySQL version*.

Comment: Apologies, had to hunt this down as its hosted on a managed server by a service provider. Seems it is the following:
10.5.18-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 (Debian 11)

Comment: ```.. TotalHours / SUM(TotalHours) OVER (PARTITION BY OfficeCode) * 100 AS HoursPercentage ..```

Comment: Hi Akina, many thanks for the above calculation, worked perfectly. Did not know/undersand the OVER PARTITION functions so appreciate the soltuion and exposure to something new

Comment: [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) - study carefully! This is a base. Very useful base..